# Unable to connect through SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, terraform

I was trying to deploy an aws ubuntu instance via terraform and I am not able to access it. I want only my ip to be able to access it so this is the code I used for the security group:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "security" {
name        = "security"
description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
vpc_id      = aws_vpc.my-vpc.id

ingress {
description      = "This is SSH"
from_port        = 22
to_port          = 22
protocol         = "tcp"
cidr_blocks      = ["here is my ip/32"]}

egress {
description      = "Any"
from_port        = 0
to_port          = 0
protocol         = "-1"
cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]}}
```

The error I get is " Connection timed out"

I tried doing the same thing in AWS Console and still have the same issue.
I have the .pem key and aws credidentials configured.

I tried putty, aws console and <<ssh -i "Main-Key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-3-91-208-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com>> after I did <<chmod 400 Main-Key.pem>> into my WSL Terminal.

Comment: Hi Rareex00, does the Terraform log suggest any issues in creating the infrastructure?  Is it possible that the security group isn't getting configured or isn't getting associated with the instance?

Comment: Terraform log isn't showing any issues. Also, if I check the security section of the instance after it is being deployed it shows the security group I created and also the rules.

Comment: What happens if you edit the security group in the web console and add a rule for "My IP" letting Amazon add your IP for you?

Comment: This is the way I did it

Comment: That's how you did what? My question is, if you set this up manually through the AWS console and let AWS fill in your IP address automatically, does Amazon fill in the same IP address you have specified in the Terraform?

Comment: Is the security_group assigned to ec2 instance?

Comment: You are probably missing an IGW, i.e., this usually happens if you don't assign an IGW to the VPC, especially if you are not using the default VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to show the error output?
are you getting any error for

```
vpc_id      = aws_vpc.my-vpc.id
and 
cidr_blocks      = ["here is my ip/32"]}
```